# Plot multiple geom_line and geom_smooth objects in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have somewhat messy looking dataframes, like this one:

```
df0
# A tibble: 3 x 9
# Groups:   Sequ [1]
   Sequ Speaker Utterance  A_intpl      A_dur      B_intpl      B_dur      C_intpl     C_dur    
  <int> <chr>   <chr>      <chr>        <chr>      <chr>        <chr>      <chr>       <chr>    
1     2 ID16.A  cool >wha… 31.44786152… 10.5,17,1… 32.86993284… 9.5,16,17… 58.3368399… 14,17,17…
2     2 NA      (0.228)    32.75735987… 15.5,17,1… 30.83469006… 14.5,16.9… 26.0386462… 3,17,16,…
3     2 ID16.B  u:m Tenne… 32.05752604… 4.5,17,16… 29.95825107… 3.5,16,17… 55.9298614… 8,17,17,…
```

I want to plot the `*_intpl` values for each speaker (`A`, `B`, or `C`) for each of the three `Utterance`s in a single chart both as line charts and as trend lines.
I'm just half successful doing this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df0 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("_"), 
               names_to = c("Event_by", ".value"),   
               names_pattern = "^(.*)_([^_]+$)") %>%
  separate_rows(c(intpl, dur), sep = ",", convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Time = cumsum(dur)) %>%
  mutate(Utterance = paste0(sub(".*(.)$", "\\1",Speaker), ": ", Utterance),
         Utterance = factor(Utterance, levels = unique(Utterance))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = log2(intpl),
             group = Event_by,
             colour = Event_by)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', color = "red", formula = y~x)+
  facet_wrap(~ Utterance, ncol = 1, scales= "free_x")
```

**Half successful** because the line plots and trend lines are *side-by-side, as if in three columns*, whereas they **should be in rows, one below the other** - how can that be achieved?

[image]

Reproducible data:

```
structure(list(Sequ = c(2L, 2L, 2L), Speaker = c("ID16.A", NA, 
"ID16.B"), Utterance = c("cool >what part?<", "(0.228)", "u:m Tennessee="
), A_intpl = c("31.4478615210995,31.5797510648522,31.7143985369445,31.651083739602,31.5806035086034,36.8956763912703,36.2882129597292,35.2124499461012,34.1366869324732,34.1366869324732,32.1927035724058,30.2487202123383,28.3047368522709,26.3607534922035,30.5278334848495,30.5919390424853,30.8898529369568,31.578968913188,31.9011198738002,32.1543265113196,31.9708002079533,31.966536408565,31.8762658607759,31.8994741472105,31.4215913971938,32.1510578328563,31.7863350712876,32.4685052625667,31.7422271490296,32.3286054977263,31.9998974949481,32.5177992323864,32.4727499785435,32.9310888953766,32.7592010033585,33.2231711877427,33.1593949301066,33.2432973964816,33.2569729073414,33.492144800249,33.317650964723,33.4835787832119,33.2377190454279,32.9200836384356,32.9684568771567,32.6400987016883,27.5447101464944,29.3948945479171,35.3449171857603,33.5932932239592,31.8416692621581,30.0900453003569,32.7850431084597,32.7589003618266,32.8365550655013,32.386716057622,32.8420792704881,32.6909995562489,32.6269434402016,32.7370944106334,32.7529759209752,32.6528826975113,32.3663573764448,32.7326853004792,32.6930038462418,32.8975978772676,33.1752899475416,33.2034433355001,33.0667431432803,32.6322933080614,33.2503168843178,32.7573598713719", 
"32.7573598713719,32.7531704791313,32.7366130631104,32.918942216354,32.8309939530596,32.3856893430525,32.5368873543441,32.5628510484821,32.5628510484821,32.5628510484821,32.5506564332008,32.7477119716583,32.3458470743288,32.0575260428013", 
"32.0575260428013,32.1628824338111,32.0093334061923,32.1461460586991,31.9080762250966,31.9469105074833,31.7431187667232,31.7194255656503,31.7394296413187,31.8594986292975,31.7498243274746,31.9069142374258,32.0835520942767,31.6257067057109,31.757232379438,31.9036689124911,32.1319749301918,31.7203280774998,31.7877137245706,32.3030946636177,32.2800139298454,32.164646135728,32.3636504940227,32.5657818936495,32.3859453482697,32.4797898358193,32.5319835105237,32.92233491509,32.8240561109448,32.664496027779,33.1835064752029,33.0366413969703,33.0406288190821,33.3232964677672,33.2206260057731,33.1537134269402,33.2783471506207,33.2933281566788,33.5322350394609,33.3815736723684,33.7905544185063,33.6143820666896,33.7490659591585,33.7260102344634,34.0721931066557,34.0455026427054,34.3735788774521,34.2888420421073,34.3913721165542,34.5982135545306,34.4417202731001,34.6586347152449,31.1590521215434,31.3276405983897,28.2379253186548,31.133030931336,34.0715906921349,35.8967950760285,35.9334551147377,35.8565504335515,35.7446081905229,35.6300325834155,35.8390086948751,35.9711743270411,36.0029493274176,35.8891056768339"
), A_dur = c("10.5,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,0.5", 
"15.5,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,12.5", "4.5,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,5.5"
), B_intpl = c("32.8699328424689,32.8154348109057,32.5454364786882,32.408257038977,32.5304564519672,32.3270203236281,31.9233218634346,32.0166346064182,31.7360745988363,31.7546527359571,31.8603220354065,31.6520061326962,31.5603191463274,31.3357561466519,31.0976090032219,31.1405090978825,31.1697180784961,31.0863999545386,31.3126984044729,30.580776446803,30.7137016246273,31.0801914571091,31.2343922096768,31.2749857511594,31.3488604642844,30.9327390960718,31.0750482778561,31.1849119826023,31.4180114886183,31.5284273181104,31.147361398529,31.1128597713973,31.5551385744611,31.7479939892741,31.5890352680344,31.5470790538009,31.5427330200078,31.3901913024084,31.5423214446953,31.4814325586741,31.4937336232021,31.3483738841556,31.2516462059018,31.2233881922543,31.2572951780583,31.0087226975291,31.1197589042273,31.053748381687,30.8202174718598,30.845143129195,30.8727194789634,30.4231467151428,30.7254093759809,30.2757746547116,30.6047530953025,29.6835591414008,28.257421076205,29.4634886416064,29.183064807185,28.6935506287734,29.3989017421637,30.8936090542518,30.6884831327852,30.805770713392,30.6938909098627,30.8317757801268,30.8509115577427,30.6836198471168,30.7979978629801,31.0260101704105,30.6248844591805,30.8346900656087", 
"30.8346900656087,30.9826158466835,29.814086001996,29.7839590794955,30.7928804535206,31.1589874726521,31.0547403039501,31.2268131145794,31.155503802286,31.3036925274762,31.4782621660348,31.0928322383151,31.589958621025,29.9582510795225", 
"29.9582510795225,29.9796434055214,29.9405638729798,30.2602098442174,30.5011865525849,30.6753859842987,28.9331380886365,30.7736467776919,30.8457967803438,30.843630408183,30.8767570425033,30.9178344980247,30.734598946287,30.8877440413271,30.9225051837881,30.9534076039184,31.0172861192043,30.9371712793451,30.9806052132295,31.0593603717961,31.1156928565737,30.4713263393479,26.028518302418,28.1426546887905,29.4308434671559,30.7190322455213,31.2289674937063,31.7389027418913,32.2488379900763,32.7587732382613,33.2687084864463,33.7786437346312,34.2885789828162,34.7985142310012,35.3084494791862,35.8183847273712,36.3283199755562,36.8382552237412,37.3481904719262,37.8581257201112,38.3680609682962,25.5986933949893,29.7968031963901,30.5336819967028,30.1876589408847,30.4260367500101,30.2997107671214,30.3429716412578,30.3537316791924,30.4111899964144,30.7293520851914,30.7778983966343,30.9712137067708,30.9072589183658,31.0696990205164,30.5713926084448,31.3458855877875,31.4169903025083,31.5148974986093,31.5972499257413,31.2293401943969,31.2033325602348,31.1657434266985,30.6784877073261,30.6991365599664,30.6763195188897"
), B_dur = c("9.5,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17.0000000000146,16.9999999999854,16,17,16.9999999999854,16.0000000000146,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17.0000000000146,16.9999999999854,16,17,16.9999999999854,16.0000000000146,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17.0000000000146,16.9999999999854,16,17,16.9999999999854,16.0000000000146,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17.0000000000146,16.9999999999854,16,17,16.9999999999854,16.0000000000146,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17.0000000000146,16.9999999999854,16,2.5", 
"14.5,16.9999999999854,16.0000000000146,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17.0000000000146,13.4999999999854", 
"3.5,16,17,16.9999999999854,16.0000000000146,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17.0000000000146,16.9999999999854,16,17,16.9999999999854,16.0000000000146,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17.0000000000146,16.9999999999854,16,17,16.9999999999854,16.0000000000146,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,7.5"
), C_intpl = c("58.3368399069697,58.249224089011,59.5198368051218,58.8722012497097,58.4418996252205,58.5849059154389,59.2752163985494,52.8407480422202,51.6276603912397,48.0255346632529,44.753541512539,41.4815483618252,38.2095552111114,34.9375620603975,31.6655689096837,28.3935757589698,25.121582608256,19.4712933827274,22.0108873782783,24.5504813738291,24.8441573376901,24.6902151101703,24.4029572181118,24.9753161974674,24.8664406826514,24.8486668451201,25.1137001504163,25.1142578332509,25.4902077628339,25.4075561268027,25.6622548410237,61.2421678149908,25.1600975771354,25.6667198263373,25.442560744158,25.8736383423437,25.5859074180431,24.7860400673889,24.4337707697216,24.3214953242744,23.915753514736,23.7363185577661,23.7186569801299,23.4313514771952,23.5730151254578,62.5124513171595,23.3260531660862,23.4498217326665,23.2145314844252,57.5586745434594,63.4646233226955,23.0706406704345,23.3318690599491,62.044649715831,62.2720656330432,22.2532276715887,62.7059140614625,22.9511208849958,22.5603175709988,23.3456453893988,63.2523901625561,60.6655429980934,60.2358824325868,59.957910796633,57.3999702562457,54.8277282980263,43.0269305132552,31.2261327284841,19.425334943713,22.7319906068577,26.0386462700023", 
"26.0386462700023,29.345301933147,32.6519575962917,35.9586132594364,48.3773995023798,60.7961857453232,49.4980424442242,55.9907960862667,57.2956837917999,58.1409925994177,59.025022056064,60.0098263540792,60.4028460580062,61.2629030450653,55.9298614021542", 
"55.9298614021542,55.3877180252389,61.3547152702855,61.7847919095391,56.2457623439544,62.5477315546977,62.3078007189967,62.4272469013149,57.6479672147315,62.9844338801191,58.0081708266629,63.3872796098875,59.0138830718112,58.0612924481098,58.38680047729,58.687179350318,63.8724230039733,63.4126777597892,63.6865154626743,63.5670658627636,63.4496590540706,63.7595297692908,58.9069708176601,63.4547681163061,64.3198376700797,63.415319961042,64.0985879957056,64.1201809531605,63.677902665454,64.1934303628317,64.4682003346273,64.2868853545462,24.8444135816353,64.1579626357752,63.8897139146875,58.5472675827292,64.5784992977498,64.0848591719068,63.8841268679761,64.2901359712354,64.395692486112,64.5425896391638,64.8060565909917,64.3618830026368,64.7088481705444,64.5005944199885,64.5540289192148,64.7408010459365,63.378880767685,63.3415589069662,63.5362700331647,63.5924807719723,63.575801461932,63.6799360982113,64.0041021410894,64.3144923757986,63.8692943755376,63.8594574363473,64.2731841085802,63.3314657812309,64.2758880216293,64.1011768977101,64.0261661917799,64.2865302330478,63.724697791255,64.1202175712152"
), C_dur = c("14,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,14", 
"3,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,8", "8,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,17,16,17,2"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), groups = structure(list(Sequ = 2L, 
    .rows = structure(list(1:3), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a possible solution with use of `grid.arrange()` func from `library(gridExtra) library(grid)` packages.

I've wrapped your data into unique charts and combined them together into arranged chart.

```
df1 = df0 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("_"), 
               names_to = c("Event_by", ".value"),   
               names_pattern = "^(.*)_([^_]+$)") %>%
  separate_rows(c(intpl, dur), sep = ",", convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Time = cumsum(dur)) %>%
  mutate(Utterance = paste0(sub(".*(.)$", "\\1",Speaker), ": ", Utterance),
         Utterance = factor(Utterance, levels = unique(Utterance)))
```

Set chart objects into enviroment:

```
for (i in unique(df1$Event_by)){
  for (j in levels(df1$Utterance)){
    assign(x = paste0(i,j), value = ggplot(data = df1[df1$Event_by == i & df1$Utterance == j,], aes(x = Time, y = log2(intpl))) +
             geom_line()+
             geom_smooth(method = 'lm', color = "red", formula = y~x))
  }
}
```

Create grided chart:

`library(gridExtra) library(grid)`

```
grid.arrange(
`AA: cool >what part?<`,
`AB: u:m Tennessee=` ,
`ANA: (0.228)`      ,
`BA: cool >what part?<` ,
`BB: u:m Tennessee=`  ,
`BNA: (0.228)`  ,
`CA: cool >what part?<` ,
`CB: u:m Tennessee=` ,
`CNA: (0.228)` ,
nrow = 3)
```

[image]

Although i think there should be better solution for that.
You can also try to explore below articlesfor arranging plots:
http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/81-ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/
https://ggplot2-book.org/facet.html
Moreover, there's is no themming added to my solution

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I need to add the `Utterance` though above the rows. And the `Speaker` Id (A, B, or C) must be shown with each row. How can that be done?

Comment: so i found this article on annotating grid.arrange(), it might be useful  
https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/78